# French Citizenship through Grandma

Tags: citizenship, french-citizens

I have a question I've been searching to find the answer to. My grandma fled France due to WW2 with her mom. She was from Strasbourg, but never gained citizenship in the US. I was born in the US and so was my mother, but she isn't wanting to gain citizenship in France. I am moving to France this year, but need to know if I have any way to gain citizenship through my grandma? Any advice or places to look would help! 
Thank you

Comment: In what year were you born? Is your grandmother still alive?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify, putting on hold.